# SAS parametric model with regularization

Tags: sas, statistics, regression

I would like to create a multivariate regression model in SAS with regularization. The model can be linear or non-linear but I would like to ensure the coefficients are small and positive.
How can I do it?
Example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what constitutes small coefficients in your case, but `proc qlim` allows for both simple and complex coefficient restrictions. For the sake of demonstration, let's assume that you want a model whose coefficients are all between -1 and 1.  `bounds` is an easy solution to this problem.

```
proc qlim data=sashelp.cars;
    model horsepower = cylinders mpg_city;
    bounds -1 <= cylinders <= 1
         , -1 <= mpg_city <= 1
    ;
run;
```

The model converges and gives us an answer. You could also do a more complex restriction using the `restrict` statement.

```
proc qlim data=sashelp.cars;
    model horsepower = cylinders mpg_city;
    restrict mpg_city + cylinders <= 1
    ;
run;
```

Even further complexity in restrictions, such as nonlinear, will require `proc model`.

```
proc model data=sashelp.cars;
    endo horsepower;
    exo cylinders mpg_city;

    horsepower = b0 + b1*cylinders + b2*mpg_city;

    restrict b1/b2 >= 0;

    fit;
run;
```

`proc model` is one of the most flexible regression procedures. As such, it requires a lot of manual input. With `proc model`, you must declare your dependent & independent variables, and type out each parameter. It can automatically determine parameter variables as long as you declare your dependent/independents.

Comment: This is very helpful! Regarding small coefficients, I would prefer not to specify a hard constraint. What I had in mind was some kind of regularization, e.g. to add the mean square of the coefficients to the model error. Is there a way to do that in the above models?